# Add calculated column to mySQL table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to add column 'new_id' to table 'items_backup' with the following MySQL expression:

```
ALTER TABLE `items_backup`
ADD COLUMN `new_id` DOUBLE 
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (`id`*100) STORED;
```

It is the multiplication of column 'id' by 100.

This is returning the error:

```
 MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GENERATED ALWAYS AS (`id`*100) STORED' at line 3
```

MySQL Version: **5.6.51**

Can anyone help?

Comment: What's wrong with the statement you included in the question?

Comment: Thanks @Shadow, please see my edit above.

Comment: What is **precise** MySQL version?

Comment: Generated columns were introduced in version 5.7.

Comment: @Akina that's a good question, I don't know...

Comment: Execute `SELECT VERSION();`

Comment: 5.6.51 this is the version

Comment: Your version does not support generated columns. Upgrade.

Comment: Ok @Akina I got it, thank you for your help!